# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Slug' of undefined"

Tags: postman

The below loop iterates and prints the correct "Slug" values in console. But, it is throwing error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Slug' of undefined". Can anyone please let me know why I'm getting this error?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

    var slugname = (xmlData.searchresults.result[i].Slug);
    console.log(slugname);

    if (slugname === assetname) {
        pm.test("Ingested Story is Published.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem: you try to get index doesn't exist (Array index out of bound).

In the last iteration, `i = count` then `xmlData.searchresults.result[count] = undefinded`. When you try to access a value of property of `undefined`, you will get error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'Slug' of undefined"`

How to fix: `loop from 0 to < count`, not `<=count`